# How do I declare a one-to-many Map in Hibernate's XML file?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-4.x

I'm trying to create a one-to-many Map relationship and I'm having trouble declaring it in the Hibernate (4.x) mapping file. I just... can't figure it out.

The entity classes are something like this, where I want to use `IPLogEntry#ip` as the map key (it is immutable):

```java
class User {

    private long id;
    private Map<String,IPLogEntry> ipHistory = new HashMap<String,IPLogEntry>();
    ... other fields;

    public void addIPEntry (String ip) {
        IPLogEntry e = ipHistory.get(ip);
        if (e == null) {
            e = new IPLogEntry(this, ip);
            ipHistory.put(ip, e);
        }
        e.doOtherStuff(...);
    }

}

class IPLogEntry {

    private long id;
    private User user;
    private String ip;
    ... other fields;

    IPLogEntry (User user, String ip) {
        this.user = user;
        this.ip = ip;
        ... init other fields;
    }

}
```

And tables like:

```
╔═══════════════════╗   ╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ users             ║   ║ ip_log                                           ║
╟─────────────┬─────╢   ╟─────────────┬───────────────┬──────────────┬─────╢
║ id (bigint) │ ... ║   ║ id (bigint) │ user (bigint) │ ip (varchar) │ ... ║
╚═════════════╧═════╝   ╚═════════════╧═══════════════╧══════════════╧═════╝
```

Note that `ip_log.ip` is both the map key *and* the `IPLogEntry#ip` field value.

And after a bunch of hand-waving I've got this failed attempt at a mapping (by the way, I don't need cascade `delete` support right now... don't ask):

```xml
<class name="d13.dao.User" table="users">
    <id name="id"><generator class="native"/></id>
    <map name="ipHistory" cascade="save-update,merge">
        <key column="user"/>
        <map-key column="ip" type="string"/>
        <element type="d13.dao.IPLogEntry"/>
    </map>
    ...
</class>

<class name="d13.dao.IPLogEntry" table="ip_log">
    <id name="id"><generator class="native"/></id>
    <many-to-one name="user" class="d13.dao.User" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="ip" not-null="true"/>
    ...
</class>
```

That gets me this on initialization:

```
Error: creating static hibernate session factoryCould not determine type for: 
    d13.dao.IPLogEntry, 
    at table: users_ipHistory,
    for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(elt)]
```

I think the `IPLogEntry` side is right, it's the `User` side and the usage of `map` that I'm having trouble with.

I've been staring at:

- [The Hibernate Manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/collections.html), but I just can't wrap my head around `map`, `map-key`, and `element`.
- [This "tutorial"](https://www.javatpoint.com/mapping-map-in-collection-mapping), but that uses a basic `String` instead of a full object for the element type, and also I can't actually tell what purpose that example code serves so it's hard to relate to.
- [This wikibooks page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Maps), but it's JPA mappings not Hibernate.

I can't figure out what to do. So I know this is a basic question, but, what mapping descriptor should I use to make this work?

Comment: Can somebody *please* compliment my ASCII-art tables so that I can feel good about myself today? They took a really long time!

Comment: Wonderful! I just want a copy'n'paste'n'format tool for tables here on SO >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's very simple with annotation-based mapping

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = { PERSIST, MERGE })
@MapKey(name = "ip")
private Map<String, IPLogEntry> ipHistory = new HashMap<>();
```

I'm not experienced in XML mapping, nevertheless it should be:

```
<class name="d13.dao.User" table="users">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <map name="ipHistory" cascade="save-update,merge" inverse="true">
        <key column="user_id"/>
        <map-key column="ip" type="string"/>
        <one-to-many class="d13.dao.IPLogEntry"/>
    </map>
    ...
</class>

<class name="d13.dao.IPLogEntry" table="ip_log">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="user" class="d13.dao.User" column="user_id" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="ip" not-null="true"/>
    ...
</class>
```

See [Example 7.29. Bidirectional association with indexed collection](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-indexedbidirectional)

Comment: Ah ha! I knew I was missing something (`<one-to-many/>`). Excellent, I can once again proceed with my plans for world domination.

Comment: You have to hurry, I almost finished the GUI for my personal terminator army ;)